# GET working with Postman, but not with Ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm attempting to do a simple GET request from a server hosting some account data. The request requires an Authorization header in order to function correctly. I have performed the GET request and retrieved the data successfully in Postman, but attempting to do so in Javascript via Ajax results in a "Invalid HTTP status code 405" error.

Below is a link to a fiddle and a screenshot of the Postman settings. Thanks.!

```
$.ajax({
    beforeSend: function(xhrObj){
            xhrObj.setRequestHeader("Authorization","Bearer tj7LTLycpQC6DRup5BkHUO7uVbYaAZI40");
    },
    type: "GET",
    url: "https://api05.iq.questrade.com/v1/accounts",
    success: function(e){
            console.log(e)
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Ldjbp2j8/1/

[POSTMAN SETTINGS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lWjf7.png)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From Chrome's JS console:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 405 (Method Not Allowed)

Because you are adding an Authorization header, you have made the request *complex*. This requires the browser to make a [preflight OPTIONS request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests) to ask for permission to send the complex request.

The server you are making the request to is responding saying that OPTIONS requests are not allowed to that URL.

You will need to modify the server so that it responds appropriately to the preflight CORS request.

---

Postman doesn't need to make a preflight request because your browser trusts Postman's code. It doesn't know if it can trust the code it received from JSFiddle (AKA *potential evil hacker site*) with the data api05.iq.questrade.com (AKA *potential online banking or company Intranet site*) is willing to share with it.

Comment: If I don't have access to the server, am I out of luck?

Comment: @dgalati54 — As far as making a direct request to it with Ajax is concerned: yes.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the console errors:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://api05.iq.questrade.com/v1/accounts.
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
Origin 'http://fiddle.jshell.net' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 405.
```

This is the CORS issue. Browsers sent OPTIONS aka pre-flight request to the server if the domain doesn't match with the domain of the running code.
And you must add the required headers to the responses as well.

You must modify server to handle that.

You can also use JSONP as an alternative.

Comment: "You can also use JSONP as an alternative" — No, you can't. JSONP doesn't allow setting HTTP headers at all.

Comment: Yes. You are correct. I ment alternative to the whole solution.